# Why are streamlit_echarts not visualized in multitabs?

Tags: python, streamlit, echarts

I want a 4-tab page in Streamlit: 2 echarts + 2 plotly.

**Why is any echart plot (but the first) not visualized, while plotly's ones are ok?**

(The real app needs a Sankey with special features that only Echarts can provide, so using another library (after extensive research) is not feasible: as in this stripped down example, only the first Sankey is visualised, not the next ones, as echarts "forgets" to refresh the visualisation after switching the tab)

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_echarts import st_echarts
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 = st.tabs(["echarts_tab1", "echarts_tab2", "plotly_tab3", "plotly_tab4"])

def echarts_random_options():
    return {
        "xAxis": {"type": "category", "data": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]},
        "yAxis": {"type": "value"},
        "series": [
            {"data": list(np.random.random(size=7) * 800),
             "type": "line"}
        ],
    }

def plotly_random_fig():
    return ff.create_distplot([np.random.randn(200)], ["values"], bin_size=[.1, .25, .5])

with tab1:
    st_echarts(options=echarts_random_options())
    
with tab2:
    st_echarts(options=echarts_random_options())
    
with tab3:
    st.plotly_chart(plotly_random_fig(), use_container_width=True)

with tab4:
    st.plotly_chart(plotly_random_fig(), use_container_width=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

add this to your code

```
streamlit_style = """
    <style>
    iframe[title="streamlit_echarts.st_echarts"]{ height: 1000px;} 
   </style>
    """
st.markdown(streamlit_style, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

See this https://github.com/andfanilo/streamlit-echarts/issues/43

Comment: Avoid code only/link answer and provide the explanation directly into the body of your answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34819028)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same problem. If several graphs are displayed in different tabs, streamlit_echarts does not display them all, you have to refresh the page and click quickly on the desired tab if you want to view the graph associated with it, which is not a normal behavior.

I managed to fix it by moving all my graphics into streamlit expanders but that's not really convenient for users.

Hopefully someone from the streamlit dev team will see this and fix it.